# Equation with irrational exponents

Tags: calculus, abstract-algebra, complex-numbers

I am reading a book and there is this statement which I don't know how to prove. The claim is: the equation $$x^s-Ax^{s-r}-B=0$$ has infinitely many solutions if $r/s$ is irrational. This is about computing eigenvalues, so I assume we are looking for complex solutions. For simplicity, let us assume $A=B=s=1$ and $r$ is irrational, so we have the equation $$x-x^{1-r}=1.$$ My idea for the infinite number of solutions would be the fact that raising $x$ to an irrational numbers requires the use of the logarithm, which is multivalued, but is this the reason? Could we say the same if the solutions were real?

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct that it is the multivalued logarithm of $x$ that leads to an infinite number of solutions.  We can write the equation as $$x-e^{(1-r)(\log x+2n\pi i)}=1$$ If $r$ were rational there would only be a finite set of numbers of the form $rn \pmod 1$ but if $r$ is irrational there is an infinite set.

Comment: Sorry I thought I had understood your answer but I don't. Could you provide more details? I don't get what you mean with numbers of the form $rn$ mod $1$. Sorry about the inconvenience!

Comment: It is just the fractonal part of $rn$.  $n$ must be an integer. If $r$ is rational, $nr \pmod 1$ will repeat with the denominator of $r$ so there will only be a finite set of values.